# how to remove default close button in a modalDialogbox

Tags: javascript, html

I tried a lot...
But i couldn't.

Can anyone tell me how to remove close button of Modal dialog box in HTML?

I want to close it only if some given activties are performed.

Comment: Hide it with CSS, then use JS to show it once your criteria are met? There are endless modal dialog plugins out there, plus many people implement their own, so how are we to know what *you* are using if you don't tell us?

Answer (score 0):

```
 <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
```

user `data-dismiss` or simply remove the button which is having `data-dismiss` model class

Comment: @Vivek - FYI, html/xml code snippet are not visible unless you format them using either the code button in the toolbar, ie `{}` OR indent the line four or more spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the above line from your code it will help  I think

```
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
```